# Ошибка во Фрейме

Tags: html

Подскажите, пожалуйста, где здесь ошибка:

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<FRAMESET ROWS="50%,*, 60,0,0,0" FRAMEBORDER=0 FRAMESPACING=0 BORDERCOLOR=#000000>
   <FRAME SRC="/game/loc=1.php" NAME="_locations" SCROLLING="AUTO" FRAMEBORDER=0>
   <frameset cols="*,250" FRAMEBORDER=0 FRAMESPACING=0 BORDERCOLOR=#000000>
     <FRAME SRC="/game/chat.php" NAME="_chat" SCROLLING="YES" FRAMEBORDER=0>
     <FRAME SRC="/game/online.php" NAME="_online" SCROLLING="YES" FRAMEBORDER=0>
</FRAMESET>
   <FRAME SRC="/game/input.php" NAME="" SCROLLING="NO" FRAMEBORDER=0 NORESIZE>
   <FRAME SRC="" NAME="_work" NORESIZE>
   <FRAME SRC="" NAME="_chat_work" NORESIZE>
   <FRAME SRC="" NAME="_chat_add" NORESIZE>
</FRAMESET>

<noframes><body bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
Ваш браузер не поддерживает фреймы
</body></noframes>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: главная ошибка - html в аперкейсе :)

Comment: @AlexWindHope
Не сбивайте человека с толку! Теги в html можно писать в uppercase. 
http://www.htmlhelp.com/faq/html/design.html#tag-case

Comment: @zavtramen - Никто его с толку не сбивает, если у вас **напрочь отсутствует чувство юмора** то тут я вам не доктор...

Да и я не сбиваю человека а "тонко нмекаю" что адекватные товарисчи в апперкейсе html не пишут

Comment: @AlexWindHope Человек сюда пришел за помощью. В данном случае если менять регистр букв, то ошибка у автора не пропадет. Это будет пустая трата времени.
PS. C чувством юмора у меня все нормально, а Вас похоже все таки задело, что Ваши шутки не могу рассмешить каждого первого человека ;)

Comment: Похоже... все-таки... Вы адресом не ошиблись?:)

Вам на форум гадалок...

Comment: [http://validator.w3.org][1] говорит, что ошибок 27. Все расписывать не буду - сходите туда и посмотрите сами.

[1]:http://validator.w3.org

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<body></body>` удали.

Comment: Тег <FRAMESET> - заменяет тег <BODY> и используется для разделения экрана

Answer (score 2):

Тег `<frameset>` - что-то вроде вместо `<body>`, поэтому кого-то одного надо убрать.